# Updated MySQL: MySQL Daemon has failed to start

Tags: mysql, daemon, socket

Just updated my MySQL on CentOS when I did `yum update`. My website threw some MySQL errors and I found out that MySQL wasn't running:

```
# /etc/init.d/mysqld start
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting MySQL:  [FAILED]
```

I receive this error:

```
2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect
```

The file doesn't exist and it isn't in my `/tmp` folder either.

---

MySQL Upgrade error:

```
# mysql_upgrade
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
Running 'mysqlcheck with default connection arguments
mysqlcheck: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when try
ing to connect
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

---

MySQL Error log:

```
101107 12:52:28 [Warning] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Option '--set-variable' is deprecated. Use --variable-name=value instead.
101107 12:52:28 [Note] Plugin 'ndbcluster' is disabled.
/usr/libexec/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
101107 12:52:28 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
101107 12:52:28  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 30688749
101107 12:52:28 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: unknown option '--skip-bdb'
101107 12:52:28 [ERROR] Aborting

101107 12:52:28  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
101107 12:52:34  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 30688749
101107 12:52:34 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

101107 12:52:34 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

2nd time:

```
101107 12:52:34 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
101107 13:19:44 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
101107 13:19:44 [Warning] option 'innodb-additional-mem-pool-size': signed value 204800 adjusted to 524288
101107 13:19:44 [Warning] option 'innodb-log-buffer-size': signed value 204800 adjusted to 262144
101107 13:19:44 [Note] Plugin 'ndbcluster' is disabled.
/usr/libexec/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
101107 13:19:44 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
101107 13:19:44  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 30688749
101107 13:19:44 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: unknown option '--skip-bdb'
101107 13:19:44 [ERROR] Aborting

101107 13:19:44  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
101107 13:19:49  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 30688749
101107 13:19:49 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

101107 13:19:49 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/dev.system.de.pid ended
```

These are the most recent errors that I've logged.

---

```
$ mysql_upgrade
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
Running 'mysqlcheck with default connection arguments
mysqlcheck: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly in your my.cnf

**remove**
'--skip-bdb'

Try to start it again /etc/init.d/mysqld start

it also seems like you have upgraded to a newer version 5.1
so you will need to run mysql_upgrade once the server is running

Comment: Sorry, all I know is that I ran "yum update" and the whole thing fell apart. I checked my.cnf and the directories are still correct. I can still run "mysql" but I receive the 2002 error. How would I do the mysql upgrade binary?

Comment: Ok we really need to see the logs...

run something like this
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/dev.system.de.pid

Comment: Added the logs to my original post

Comment: Well my website is back up but I still can't run "mysql_upgrade". I posted the new output at the end of my post.

Comment: try mysql_upgrade -p
and put your root mysql password in...

Your not really reading these logs are you??? :P

Comment: Thanks Arenstar. Sorry but I've never delved deep into a server before.

Comment: read the logs and use the source luke

Answer (score 0):

Look in my.cnf (either /etc/mysql/my.conf or /etc/my.cnf) for the log_error directive to find out where it's logging errors. On Ubuntu it defaults to /var/log/mysql/error.log, it might be different on your system. Look there to see what the mysql server is complaining about.

Comment: Added the error log to my original post